# Async await with axios not returning errors

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I'm using async await with axios and am having trouble with the error handling. Using normal promises (example 2 below), I can get an error object when killing my local server. However, using async await, the `error` comes in as undefined (example 1 below) Does anyone know why this would be

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  timeout: 3000,
})

// example 1
try {
   await instance.get('/data/stores')
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error) // error is not defined
}
// example 2
return instance.get('/data/stores').catch(error => {
  console.log(error) // error is normal axios error
})
```

Comment: Had exactly the same trouble with firefox and chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the error was there within the catch, it is just that my debugger did not recognize it.

Answer (score 17):

The error response is stored inside `response` property. For some reason you can't see this in Chrome's console.

So in your catch block do:

```
console.log(error.response)
```